# Wordpress add Jquery Mega Menu to top of the page with search box

Tags: css, wordpress

I would to add [Jquery Mega Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-mega-menu/) to top menu with search box.

I was able to add the menu to top but the search box is not showing correctly.

please see Demo2.sarwana.co.uk

I added following css but still cant get it to show in my menu correctly.

```css
.woocommerce-product-search {
    display: none;
}
.woocommerce-product-search {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8gFW78WkjMSeVFBVnA1NFBmX3c/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-2-item ul li a {
    background-position-y: top !important;
}
```

Check the backgrounds positions. This rule fix it

Comment: .search a, .search form { height: 1em; } 

and remove the new -40px margin topp!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-2-item ul li a {
    background-position-y: top !important;
    height: 1em;
}   
#dc_jqmegamenu_widget-2-item ul li form { 
    margin-top: auto; 
    height: 1em;
}
```